# How to interpolate 2D data in column format with SciPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have velocity vectors for an example grid as shown below:

[image: Example Grid]

The data are available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rnx6DTEicItaGhgJQxodnCabnTowGdCF). However, the data is stored in column format as given below:

**Input data format**

```
x1, y1, ... (velocity vectors)
x1, y2, ... (velocity vectors)
x1, y3, ... (velocity vectors)
 :   :               :
x4, y2, ... (velocity vectors)
x4, y3, ... (velocity vectors)
x4, y4, ... (velocity vectors)
```

I am trying to apply a 2D interpolation with `scipy`'s `interpolate` function. I need to double the number of grid points and interpolate and write to output file in the same column format that is:

**Desired output format (after interpolation):**

```
x1_i, y1_i, ... (velocity vectors)
x1_i, y2_i, ... (velocity vectors)
x1_i, y3_i, ... (velocity vectors)
 :   :               :
x8_i, y6_i, ... (velocity vectors)
x8_i, y7_i, ... (velocity vectors)
x8_i, y8_i, ... (velocity vectors)
```

**MWE**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
from scipy import interpolate

_data_ = np.genfromtxt('./2d_interp.dat', skip_header=1, dtype = None, delimiter = '\t')

mesh_y = (np.max(np.diff(np.sort(_data_[:,0]))))
mesh_z = (np.max(np.diff(np.sort(_data_[:,1]))))
mesh_min = min(mesh_y, mesh_z)
x_max = np.max(_data_[:,0])
x_min = np.min(_data_[:,0])
y_max = np.max(_data_[:,1])
y_min = np.min(_data_[:,1])



interp_n_cells = max(abs(x_max - x_min)/mesh_min, abs(y_max - y_min)/mesh_min)
x_interp = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 2 * interp_n_cells)
y_interp = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 2 * interp_n_cells)

xx_interp, yy_interp = np.meshgrid(x_interp, y_interp)
interp_data = np.empty(shape=(len(x_interp * y_interp),6))
interp_data[:,0] = x_interp
interp_data[:,1] = y_interp
interp_data[:,2] = _data_[0,2]
for i in range(3,5):
    f = interpolate.interp2d(_data_[:,0], _data_[:,1], _data_[:,i], kind='linear')
    interp_data[:,i] = f(x_interp, y_interp)
```

Now, how can I interpolate a 2D data with `scipy.interpolate` in column format, i.e., I need to double the number of points, interpolate and output data in the same format as the input format (given above). How can this be done with `scipy`?

Comment: The example you provide generates the error:`interp_data[:,i] = f(x_interp, y_interp)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (82,82) into shape (82)` This is because the return array has all `z_ij` corresponding to all combinations of `(x_i, y_j)`. Is this what you intend to resolve?

Comment: No, I need  the return array to be of (82x82,6), i.e., all possible combinations of x_i and y_i to be combined in to two columns.

Comment: One of the issues I see with this interoperation being successful is that your spatial resolution is 10e-2 however, your velocities are two orders of magnitude higher. You need a wrapper to normalise your data and recover the results to scale.